# Detecting If A Coordinate Is Near Polygon Edges In Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google, google-maps-api

Is there a way to add a test to see if a Lat/Long coordinate is near the edge of a polygon?

I am building very complicated polygons that have rivers and roads as borders. Because of this, it is very difficult to make the polygons 100% accurate.

A test like this could add appropriate warnings in these scenarios.

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49105017/3534952) will help you.